# Get the count of first field in the list of lists by iterating through for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

By iterating through a list of lists I am trying to get the count of the first field from all the lists within a list and implement some if-else logic. Not sure if this is possible to do within an Iterator.

```
Input:-

[ [1,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'C'],[-1,'D'],[-1,'D'] ]

Output:-

Invalid row
Invalid row
Valid row 
Invalid row
Invalid row

Comments :-
```

If the count is more than 1 for any value then all such rows are invalid otherwise the rows are valid.

Comment: Can you post a sample input and your desired output?

Comment: What determines that a row is invalid?

Comment: Added the input and output samples above..

Comment: I don't understand the output

Comment: Sorry.. I added the comments...

Comment: Why is row 1 invalid?

Comment: My bad... I just corrected the output data.... I am really sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for l in myList:
    counts[l[0]] += 1
for l in myList:
    if counts[l[0]] > 1:
        print("Invalid row")
    else:
        print("Valid row")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the counts of the first element in a counter and then do another for loop to iterate through your list of lists:

First, store counts:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [ [1,'A'],[1,'B'],[2,'C'],[-1,'D'],[-1,'D'] ]
c= Counter()
for element in l:
    c[element[0]] += 1

print c
Out: Counter({1: 2, -1: 2, 2: 1})
```

Now, Iterate through your list of lists to check which is valid and which is not:

```
for element in l:
    if c[element[0]] > 1:
        print "Invalid"
    else:
        print "Valid"
```

Follow up from the comments: If you want to append the counts to each element in the list:

```
for element in l:
    element.append(c[element[0]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to append the count to each list in l ?

Comment: Yes, that is fairly simple to do once you have all the counts, I will update my answer

Comment: The ques I have is how does c[element[0]] appends the right count to each list in the list as there are total 5 lists inside the big list?

Comment: That's because I first ran a for loop through all the lists inside "l" and stored the count in "c". "c" is a Counter. Once I have done that, I use "c" to look up the counts

Comment: I havent tested it yet.. give me few mins... I will get back to u shortly... thank u so much for taking time and answering my ques..

Comment: Append seems like doesnt work Rakesh... When I try appending it  I am getting 1 at the end of each row

Comment: My data is like this 1:201601 and I am doing my code like this .....   list.append(c[element[0].split(':')[0]])

Comment: You need to do a better job at explaining your question and data. For the situation you have described above, my code works. Sorry I couldn't help you